# Change audio format without changing audio from the command line

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, sox, i2s

I have some audio recorded form an i2s mic at 16000hz with arecord.  It sounds like it is down an octave so I want to change the file format to 32000hz.  When I try to do this with sox it edits the audio, not just the format so it still sounds wrong.

This is the sox command I am using:  `sox in.wav -r 32000 out.wav` What command should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like order matters in the command.  The correct command is:
`sox -r 32000 in.wav out.wav`

Comment: ya, it said I had to wait 48 hours before accepting my own answer.

Comment: My apologies. I should have looked at your posting date/time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the audio rate, you can do it this way with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -ar 32000 output.wav
```

Comment: This has the same problem.  It changes the audio along with the format.  I only want to change the format.

Comment: What does the word 'format' mean to you?

Comment: I have the right 1s and 0s, but the wav header specifies a 16khz sample rate, and it should say that the file has a 32khz sample rate so that it plays correctly.

Comment: I got it.  The order matters in the command.